# Is it possible to read each line of a file on command in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, filereader

In short I have a video playing on the canvas:

```
vid1.addEventListener('play', function() {
  var $this = this; //cache
  (function loop() {
    if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
      ctx1.drawImage($this, 0, 0);
      setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
    }
  })();
}, 0);
```

On each run of the function loop I would like to read a line from a text file. The file is 50 mb so I am tempted to steer away from loading the whole file into an array before starting but i have yet to find a solution that would allow me to read each line of the file with out doing that. Thank you.

Comment: Your `loop()` function only runs once though.

Comment: *"The file is 50 mb so I am tempted to steer away from loading the whole file into an array"* -- According to my experience, this isn't something you should worry about on any reasonably modern device. I have an audio production web-app that eats 200 MB+ wave files by the dozen without any problems. Unfortunately, I believe you cannot _stream_ file content on the web platform (at least not on the client from a local file), so you'll either have to open the entire thing, or use a server as the base to implement a streaming system.

Comment: @JohnWeisz thank you. I don't have much experience with loading files so I wasn't sure if file size would be a problem, this was helpful.